# The width of dropdown is changing based on selected item in Antd React

Tags: reactjs, antd

The width of the dropdown is changing based on dropdown list.

```
let drop = ['Abhiram', 'Bhanu', 'Dhanunjay Ram']
    let menu = (
        <Menu onClick={this.handleMenuClick}>
            { drop && (
                drop.map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                        <Menu.Item key={i} icon={<UserOutlined />}>{item}</Menu.Item>
                    )
                })
            )}
        </Menu>
      );
<div>
     <Dropdown overlay={menu} trigger={['click']}>                
        <Button> Abhiram </Button>
      </Dropdown>
</div>
```

So, here when i select 'Abhiram'. It display Abhiram as selected dropdown and same applies for Bhanu and Dhanunjay Ram. Here, the issue is after selecting the width of dropdown is changing.
*I don't want to change the width of dropdown after selecting from list*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width of the `Dropdown` component like so:

```
<Dropdown overlay={menu} trigger={['click']} style={{width: "100px"}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a width css property in select component :)

Answer (score 0):

set the button width of 100% work for me